# Python converting url into directory

Tags: python, url, directory

I am trying to convert a url like `"www.example.com/images/dog.png"` into directories from the current directory.

So I get a folder named `"www.example.com"`, inside that `"images"` and finally inside that the file saved as `"dog.png"`

I've tried using `urllib.url2pathname(path)` but it keeps appending `P:\` to the start of it.

Comment: I use it like url2pathname("www.google.com") and it returns "P:\www.google.com"

Comment: Just tested `urllib.url2pathname(path)` and got the correct result on Python 2.7.13. result: `www.example.com\images\dog.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `os.makedirs()` to create the directory tree, but that will fail if the final directory already exists. So you can test if it exists before attempting to create the directory tree, or use `try: ... except OSError:`. In Python 3 you can supply an `exist_ok` parameter to over-ride this behaviour, see the Python docs of [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) for further info.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

cwd = os.getcwd()

url = "www.example.com/images/dog.png"

fullname = os.path.join(cwd, url)
path, basename = os.path.split(fullname)
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

with open(fullname, 'w') as f:
    f.write('test\n')
```

---

If your system doesn't support directory names containing periods you can translate them to another character, eg `_`, like this:

```
fullname = fullname.replace('.', '_')
```

(just insert this after the `fullname = os.path.join(cwd, url)` line).

And as jwilner mentions in the comments, it's more efficient to use

```
path = os.path.dirname
```

than `path, basename = os.path.split(fullname)` if you don't need the base component of the file name (in this example `"dog.png"`).

Comment: This doesn't work because the url is not in the same format as a path directory

Comment: @Shifty: It works for me (on Linux on an ext3 filesystem) with that URL. Are you using an OS or filesystem that doesn't permit periods in pathnames? If so, you should have mentioned that in your question. And that can be easily fixed with, eg `fullname = fullname.replace('.', '_')`

Comment: I would suggest that you use `os.path.dirname` instead of `os.path.split` -- you have no need for the `basename` component, and `os.path.dirname` is more explicit. Also, the `os.path.exists` call is unnecessary -- `os.makedirs` only makes directories which do not exist.

Comment: @jwilner OTOH, the `os.makedirs` issue is a little complicated. In [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) "Raises an error exception [`OSError`] if the leaf directory already exists or cannot be created". In [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) there's an `exist_ok` parameter: "If `exist_ok` is `False` (the default), an `OSError` is raised if the target directory already exists."

Comment: Path names are not consistent across windows and linux. So using the URL as the path name explicitly does not support windows path naming conventions of the "\" backslash

Comment: @Shifty: Windows has handled forward slashes as a pathname separator for _ages_. But if this is a problem for you, see [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?os.path.normpath#os.path.normpath)

Comment: Ahh sorry I found my problem, was not removing the url scheme from the url.

Comment: @Shifty: Yeah, that will mess up your path, bigtime. :) If it's any consolation, that's an easy mistake to make. BTW, if my answer has helped you, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.